# Othello (Reversi) Online community

Tags: online, othello

Are there any online big communities similar to FICS or Chess.com for Othello (Reversi) where you can play against many players and so on?

Comment: Lots of sites- though not exclusively Othello moderately easily found by google search such as ItsYourTurn.com My wife is Othello fanatic- always playing on her mobile- The only free game it has.

Comment: @user2617804 active community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play online on Yucata http://www.yucata.de/en/GameInfo/Reversi.  Generally the games are played over days rather than "real time" though.

Lots of other great games too

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Turn The Tides](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/turn-the-tides!/id928927394?ls=1&mt=8) (I'm its developer) which has 24 different boards based on the idea of reversi. You also get to use powers and there are another 24 boards with hexagonal tiles as well. You can play offline(against the iphone) or online with real players via GameCenter.

Answer (score 2):

Server where many good players play is [Kurnik](http://www.kurnik.pl/). If you're asking about communities [this](http://www.worldothello.org/) is a website of federation that organise international tournaments.

Comment: "Kurnik" is only for polish. The international version of the same site is playok.com.

Answer (score 1):

1. The international version of "Kurnik" is [playok.com](https://www.playok.com).
2. **Othello quest** is the app where most good players play. On [android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fm.wars.reversi&hl=en&gl=US) or [iphone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/othello-quest-online-othello/id859831183).

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I released **RiseTournaments** app (real time Reversi), I organize weekly tournaments with great prizes for the top 3 players. It's free and available on the App store.

link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/risetournaments/id942714819

Comment: This answer seems a bit personally driven and has an air of spam about it, so I'd be a little careful in how you word things.

Answer (score 0):

The best sites are:
[PlayOK](https://www.playok.com/en/reversi/)
[Othello Quest](http://wars.fm/reversi)
[eOthello](https://www.eothello.com/)

You can find the ratings of the known players here:
[World Othello Federation ratings](https://www.worldothello.org/ratings)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My default site for **real time** gaming is Board Game Arena. It hosts over 200 games.  see [BGA:Reversi](https://boardgamearena.com/gamepanel?game=reversi)

[image]

[image]